# Upgrading my RAM on my ASUS laptop

Tags: laptop, memory

I use a not-too-famous ASUS laptop, with a 4 gig RAM and I want to upgrade to 8. 
The relevant specs are as follows:

```
Company: Asus
Model number:   R558UR-DM069T
Current size of RAM: 4 GB
Type: DDR4, PC 2100
NB Frequency: About 2300 MHz
No. of slots: 4
```

The above information I got from running CPU-Z on my system, and from [the site I bought my laptop from.](http://www.amazon.in/dp/B01KQB7C30/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_2?pf_rd_p=733112647&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B01HHZOYOS&pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_r=1G1DA6BSRXSES16HJFV5)

Unfortunately, CPU-Z SPD page is always blank, even if I run as administrator. Both Crucial and Kingston don't recognize my laptop model, and if I try to run their scanner, I don't know what application to open it up with. Is it OK if I buy any RAM of 4 gigs, 2200 MHz, or are all of them laptop dependent?

If I can't do that, can you guide me from here?

Comment: Try to use same frequencies of ram.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the memory is type DDR4, PC2100, the same type of memory is installed and the total amount of memory is equal or lower than the maximum allowed (look this up in the manual) it will work.

Another way to know what memory you have installed, is by opening the back of the laptop where the actual memory is installed. It usually has a sticker with type and such on it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the ASUS website we can see that this laptop is referred with another model number:

https://www.asus.com/supportonly/R558UR/HelpDesk_Download/

It should be similar to X556U, product that appears at Crucial webstite to upgrade:

http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/ASUS/x556ua

You should have to **re-check** that everything is correct and buy the RAM. The RAM module is not laptop manufacturer dependent, but the compatibility may be. Remember that you should also always buy the same type of model (frequency) that is already installed.

Probably you are aware of it but according to the amazon comments and corsair website, it is possible of upgrading to 12GB of RAM with adding 8GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

according to the following page (http://icecat.de/en_sg/p/asus/r558ur-dm069t/notebooks-R558UR-DM069T-33634414.html) this laptop just got one memory slot an supports maximum 16GB ram.

To upgrade your Ram to 8GB you have to buy one 8GB, DDR4, So-Dimm module.
At the following page are some suitable ram modules listed:
http://www.compustocx.de/de/csx-ram-arbeitsspeicher-suchen-3/8GB~2133MHz~~DDR4~~SODIMM